# Why bipolar encoding such as AMI is called bipolar?

Tags: encoding, bipolar

In bipolar encoding, we use three levels: positive, zero, and negative. The voltage level for one data element is at zero, while the voltage level for the other element alternates between positive and negative.

I understand the idea but don't know why it is called "bipolar", because in my understanding, polar means we can use positive and negative value(+,-), and for AMI, we use zero value as well, so a total of 3 values (+,-,0). And "bi-" mean twice/double, so a bipolar encoding should mean it use 4 values (twice of polar ecoding's available values), so I feel that "one and an half polar" is more suitable in this context?

Comment: I've never heard an NRZ encoding called "polar". The distinction is usually NRZ (non-return-to-zero, just + and - states) and RZ (return-to-zero), where the signalling alternates between either + or - and 0.

Comment: @Hearth - NRZI has bipolar implementations; quite common in the telecoms sector.

Comment: @PeterSmith Ah, I think I've not understood what they were asking, but after looking into that it makes more sense. I might be able to write up an answer later.

Comment: @Hearth Hi bro, looking for your answer

Comment: @amjad I've written up an answer. Please don't call me bro, though.

Comment: @Hearth No prob, brah.

Answer (score 0):

Bipolar signalling simply means that the signal goes both positive and negative. Both RZ and NRZ signals can be bipolar; RZ always is, to my knowledge.

Unipolar signalling, on the other hand, only ever goes positive with respect to the return/ground. (It could also only go negative, but that's less common.)

I haven't heard it called just "polar", but I would assume that refers to unipolar, by the way you contrast it with bipolar. It's not the number of valid signal states, but rather the number of signs used--either just positive, or both positive and negative.